# 2nd dropdown options determined by 1st dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 dropdown menus that, together, determine what combination of products the consumer is buying. The second dropdown's contents is dependent upon the first dropdown's selection. I am able to solve this easily with:

```
document.getElementById("select").options[10].style.display = 'none';
```

However, I found out that safari does not support the styling of options. This has brought me to the point I am at now, using .append() and .remove(), however these are not working as I expected. When switching back and forth between options in the first dropdown, there seems to be duplicating of options in the second dropdown. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<select class="validation" id="7b478bce31a8953385d05cdf3c1f5a1f" name="attribute[217]">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> -- Please Choose an Option -- </option>
  <option value="269">Junior</option>
  <option value="270">Aero</option>
  <option value="271">Max</option>
</select>


<select class="validation" id="9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5" name="attribute[218]">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> -- Please Choose an Option -- </option>
  <option value="167">Snow White</option>
  <option value="158">Charcoal Black</option>
  <option value="160">Electric Blue</option>
  <option value="161">Royal Blue</option>
  <option value="162">Hot Pink</option>
  <option value="163">Spring Green</option>
  <option value="164">Purple Punch</option>
  <option value="165">Sunny Yellow</option>
  <option value="166">Tangerine Orange</option>
  <option value="168">Forest Green</option>
  <option value="159">Intense Red</option>
</select>


<select class="validation" id="573f771b426f35d14337138d17deda3a" name="attribute[219]">
  <option value=""> -- Please Choose an Option -- </option>
  <option value="268" selected="selected">Cinnamint</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById('7b478bce31a8953385d05cdf3c1f5a1f').selectedIndex = 0;
  bufferForSelections = new Array();
  $('#7b478bce31a8953385d05cdf3c1f5a1f').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "269") {
      $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='168']").remove();
      document.getElementById('9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').selectedIndex = 0;
      $('#7b478bce31a8953385d05cdf3c1f5a1f').change(function() {
        $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="168">Forest Green</option>');
      });
    } else {
      if (value == "271") {
        $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='168']").remove();
        $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='166']").remove();
        $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='165']").remove();
        $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='163']").remove();
        $("#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5 option[value='161']").remove();
        $('#7b478bce31a8953385d05cdf3c1f5a1f').change(function() {
          $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="168">Forest Green</option>');
          $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="166">Tangerine Orange</option>');
          $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="165">Sunny Yellow</option>');
          $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="163">Spring Green</option>');
          $('#9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').append('<option value="161">Royal Blue</option>');
        });
        document.getElementById('9c995f36eab2fc80110590a6ad5a15f5').selectedIndex = 0;
      } else {}
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahaponek_sisu/e5m0sLmt/

And this is where this will be implemented: https://www.sisuguard.com/sisu-bundle/

I am not able to change the HTML. I am attempting to work around a limitation in BigCommerce, where the HTML is generated. Is there another way I should be attacking this?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? Populate a second dropdown based on the choice made in the first dropdown?

Comment: Correct. If 'Aero' is selected, all 11 color option are shown. If 'Junior' is selected, 10 color options (no forest green). If 'Max' is selected, 6 color options (no forest green, tangerine orange, sunny yellow, spring green, royal blue).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I think populate was the keyword I was missing while searching. Thank you, this is incredibly helpful!